# Is there a general rule of thumb regarding max RAM on old laptops?

Tags: laptop, memory

I'm talking about really old Pentium/PII/PIII laptops which usually I've seen with max RAM specs being at 64/192/512MB respectively.  I've seen a couple P3 laptops that actually support up to 1 GB RAM though, could there possibly be one that supports even more or a PI/PII laptop that supports up to 512MB RAM?

Comment: It depends on memory controller - integrated in mainboard chipset (for PI - PIII) or in microprocessors (currently)...

Comment: There's no rule of thumb. Get a hold of the manual for that specific device and look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Chipsets and their RAM limit ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_chipsets#Pentium_chipsets)):

- Pentium:

  - 430LX - 192 MB
  - 430NX - 512 MB
  - 430FX - 128 MB
  - 430MX - 128 MB
  - 430HX - 512 MB
  - 430VX - 128 MB
  - 430TX - 256 MB
- Pentium Pro/II/III

  - 450KX - 1 GB
  - 450GX - 8 GB
  - 440FX - 1 GB
  - 440LX - 1 GB EDO/512 MB SDRAM
  - 440EX - 256 MB
  - 440BX - 1 GB
  - 440GX - 2 GB
  - 450NX - 8 GB
  - 440ZX/440ZX-66   512 MB
  - 440ZX-M - 256 MB
  - 440MX - 512 MB
- Pentium II/III 8xx chipsets

  - 810  - 512 MB
  - 810E  - 512 MB
  - 810E2  - 512 MB
  - 820  - 1 GB
  - 840  - 4 GB
  - 820E  - 1 GB
  - 815  - 512 MB
  - 815E  - 512 MB
  - 815EP  - 512 MB
  - 815P  - 512 MB
  - 815G  - 512 MB
  - 815EG  - 512 MB
- Pentium III-M

  - 830M - 1 GB
  - 830MG - 1 GB
  - 830MP - 1 GB

Comment: Chipset limits ram, but the oem bios code can further restrict this limit.